# How to install Nemo Image Tools extension?

Tags: software-installation, ppa, nemo, nautilus-extensions

I've been trying to install the extension from [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/manipulate-images-in-nautilus-or-nemo.html) guide, but when I get to to the line to install:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-image-tools
```

I get:

> Unable to locate package nautilus-image-tools

Then I go to the official PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/nemo-extensions?field.series_filter=xenial), but I am not sure how to install a .xz or .gz file!

Comment: The PPA doesn't have a package for Ubuntu 16.04, which I presume is what you are using.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: @Tony - Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @Tony @ edwinks ... oh does that mean I can't get this for my very of Ubuntu? No other way?

Comment: @peteubuntu Yes, sadly they haven't put the image tools for Xenial(16.04).

Comment: That's so bad! Thx Tony.